# Why does this loop continuously run (asking player for their turn)?

Tags: python

Having an issue with the while loop for the win_checker method which I can't seem to figure out. I tried doing 2 while loops but that didn't work, so then I stuck with just one:

```
# Checking for win
def win_checker():
    global is_game_on
    if board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != "-":
        print(board[0] + " won!")
        is_game_on = False



# Start the game using a method
def start_game():
    global is_game_on
    is_game_on = True
    display_board()
    while is_game_on:
        handle_turn_x()
        win_checker()
        tie_checker()
        handle_turn_o()


start_game()
```

If I set the while loop to run only when `is_game_on` is `True`, and if my `win_checker` sets `is_game_on` to `False` (when appropriate), then why does the game keep going and ask the next player for its turn?

I suspect this is something to do with how I'm trying to jump out of the while loop.

Where am I wrong here? 
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Have you tried the `break` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition of the `while` loop is only checked when the program is "reading" the line that says

```
while <condition>:
```

I would recommend, instead of global variables, you make `win_checker` and `tie_checker` return a boolean value (`True` or `False`), and then make your `while` loop look like this:

```py
while True: # run forever
    handle_turn_x()
    if win_checker() or tie_checker():
        break # jump out of the while loop
    handle_turn_o()
    if win_checker() or tie_checker():
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! And everyone else for their feedback :D

Answer (score 0):

Globals are generally a bad idea...

instead of using a global, return True or False from that function.

Then in start_game:

```
def start_game():
    display_board()
    while True:
        handle_turn_x()
        if(not win_checker()):
            break
        tie_checker()
        handle_turn_o()



start_game()
```

Then you can do the same for the tie checker

Comment: You're still using the global variable in the `while` statement. You need to put an `if` statement after each turn.

Comment: @Barmar within the context of this code snippet, `is_game_on` is not global.  Note in the OP's code they are explicitly marking it global and modifying it in the win_checker function.

Comment: You were using the global variable before your last edit. But you need to check for a win after `handle_turn_o()`.

Comment: Actually it was me who made this solution, and I fixed it accordingly lol

I already mentioned he shouldn't use the global variable, and instead return true or false from the original function. @Barmar

Comment: My first comment was before your edit that removed `while is_game_on:`. But you're still missing the `win_checker()` after `handle_turn_o()`.

Answer (score -2):

You could simply return `is_game_on` instead of modifying the global value, for example like so:

```
# Checking for win.
def win_checker():

    if board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != "-":
        print(board[0] + " won!")
        return False
    else
        return True


# Start the game using a function.
def start_game():
    while True:
        handle_turn_x()
        if win_checker() or tie_checker():
            break

        handle_turn_o()
        if win_checker() or tie_checker():
            break
```

Now this would be a little repetitive, so I think the win and tie checkers should be included to the turn handler. Something like this:

```
while True:
    for player in ("x", "o"):
        handle_turn(player)
        if win_checker(player) or tie_checker():
            break
```

Comment: You need to call `win_checker()` again after `handle_turn_o()`

Comment: This will still let the o player play one move after x has won the game